# Basic nginx configuration (mapping URLs to files and hiding everything else)

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to make

```
/ -> /foo/index.html
/(about|people|contact) -> /foo/(about|people|contact).html
/blah.(jpg|css|js) -> /foo/blah.(jpg|css|js)
```

but also

```
/index.html -> 404
/(about|people|contact).html -> 404
* -> 404
```

So far I have:

```
  # Serve our home page.
  location / {
    root /foo/;
  }

  location = / {
    alias /foo/;
  }

  location ~ /(about|people|contact) {
    default_type text/html;
    alias /foo/$1.html;
  }

  location ~ /(.+\.(jpg|css|js)) {
    root /foo/;
  }
```

While this exposes the files I want exposed via the non-.html URLs, it doesn't 404 any files.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the very first thing I had tried (not mentioned in my question),

```
location = / { alias /foo/index.html; }
```

results in

```
"/var/www/intro/index.htmlindex.html" is not a directory
```

In my question above, I changed this to something that at least could serve the page, plus a useless line that conveyed my intention:

```
location / { root /foo/; }
location = / { alias /foo/; } # seems to be ignored
```

From http://ngxbot.lustfield.net/logs/%23nginx/2012/01/%23nginx.19.log I found that you can replace the second line with:

```
location = / { root /foo/; rewrite ^ /index.html break; }
```

Then make `location /` point somewhere else, e.g. an empty directory:

```
location / { root /var/www/; }
```

Not sure this is the most elegant solution, but it seems to work.